# what does this icon means in windows phone while wifi is on.

Tags: wifi, cellular-data, file-transfer, nokia-lumia-730, icons

I just noticed that whenever my WiFi is on this icon appears in between. I searched about this icon and I got information about it which says that this icon appears when "WiFi connection is being used to transfer data". Now I am little confused/ scared that if someone is transferring my mobile data using WiFi connection. I am not downloading or uploading any data and it still shows this icon. Kindly help me in clearing my doubts about this. Thanks in advance. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

**There are a lot of background tasks to use the network**

To name few:

- Store checking (and downloading) app updates
- E-mail sync
- Other services you use to sync your stuff (OneDrive, DropBox, etc...)
- Apps that run in background (such as Skype, Hike, WhatsApp, etc...)
- Automatic OS updates
- Sending of Feedback data

To answer your question

> Now I am little confused/ scared that if someone is transferring my
>   mobile data using WiFi connection

In Windows 10 Mobile Go to *Settings->Network & Wireless->Data Usage*. Check if data usage is allowed on Limited WiFi. Click Don't Allow button.

In Windows Phone 8.1 or lower, Go to *Settings -> Cellular network*. There is option *"during limited WiFi connection"* - make sure you have option *"do not use cellular data"* checked.

Also, your personal data are never transferred unless you specifically say so.